# C# webbrowser не сохраняет куки

Tags: c#, webbrowser, html, http

Здравствуйте, захожу на сайт через webbrowser, а мне в ответ подгружается страница с сообщением о том, что в моем браузере не включены куки или я нахожусь в режиме невидимка. Как решить это проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, у вас в *Свойствах браузера* (ПУ) указано не сохранять куки.
Мне кажется это правдоподобным, потому что webbrowser построен на основе IE.

Я бы еще попробовал покопаться в этом элементе и попробовать нащупать куки вручную, например как [здесь](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet.internetsetcookie), или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185171/use-cookies-from-cookiecontainer-in-webbrowser)